# Where Is "No Longer Mine"?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Where is the location called **No Longer Mine**?

I am trying to seduce a [Lumberwood](http://www.ign.com/wikis/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/Lumberwood) so that I can begin training it into an [Umberwood](http://www.ign.com/wikis/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/Umberwood), which supposedly has [the best final defense](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/998014-ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch/65295773) in the game.

On a related note (and I supposed I'll find out once I get there), my team is in their low 30s right now. At what level can the group comfortably beat the Lumberwoods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Longer Mine is southeast of Autumnia and south of the Spindle.

The Spindle is east of Autumnia.

[image: No Longer Mine]

There should be a glowing spot that periodically spawns giving you 555G.

You can get a Lumberwood Ticket from Errand 075 that will allow you to get the familiar with the sign you are looking for (save beforehand and keep resetting until you do). (A Planet Sign Lumberwood is very rare, but it has better defense compared to a Double Star Signed one)

Answer (score 1):

The Lumberwood lives on No Longer Mine Island, which is North of Teeheeti (Where the Fairygrounds is).  You can get there by boat, but I'd advise being in the mid-to-late 30's before you attempt it.  I wasn't doing that much grinding, and I had a little trouble until after I'd completely cleared Hamelin's quest line.

The Lumberwood spawns consistently in the southwestern forest on this island.  I've found them very rarely in other encounters.  Your best bet is to Gateway to Motorville and back to reset the encounter and fight it over and over again.

If you wait until you can get the Lumberwood Ticket from Errand 075, you're going to be waiting until you've fought some relatively difficult monsters *after* the end of the game.  You're unlikely to get the maximum stats variant of the Lumberwood from serenading them, but at least you'll have one to use for the interim - it's a very powerful defender.